# How to switch left and right skeleton position?

Tags: armature

I just started using blender. For some unknown reason, the skeleton become mirrored where all the left bone was placed to right,, like their were all switch places, rotating "arm_upper_R" makes the object Left arm move. still working but theyre in the wrong places, how to fix this??

Comment: look at the top right of the 3D View, you must have the X symmetry option activated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.